# How to write a large amount of logs with log4j or winston? Out of Memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, out-of-memory

**Logging of NodeJS**

As a begginner of nodejs, I wrote test code like followed. But the memory is increasing larger and larger, and sometimes nothing output (changed it by multiple ways).

There're 2 famous logging module, [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) and [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston). Take log4js as example.

**1. main.js**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    let log4js = require("./log4js-config.js");
    let logger = log4js.getLogger("log4js_main");

    for(let i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++){

            logger.log("info", "info message " + i + ".");

    }

})();
```

**2. log4js-config.js**

```
module.exports = (function(){
    "use strict";
    let Log4js = require("log4js");
    Log4js.configure(
        {
             "appenders" : [
                 {   "type" : "logLevelFilter"
                     ,"level" : "ALL"
                     ,"appender" : {
                         "type" : "console"
                     }
                 }
                 ,{  "type" : "logLevelFilter"
                     ,"level" : "ALL"
                     ,"appender" : {
                         "type" : "dateFile"
                         ,"filename" : "./logs/log4js_date"
                         ,"pattern" : "-yyyyMMdd.log"
                         ,"alwaysIncludePattern" : false
                         ,"maxLogSize" : 209715200
                         ,"_maxLogSize" : "200M = 200 * 1024 * 1024 = 209715200"
                         ,"category" : "log4js.dateFile" 
                     }
                 }
                 ,{  "type" : "logLevelFilter"
                     ,"level" : "ALL"
                     ,"appender" : {
                         "type" : "file"
                         ,"filename" : "./logs/log4js_size.log"
                         ,"maxLogSize" : 209715200
                         ,"_maxLogSize" : "200M = 200 * 1024 * 1024 = 209715200"
                         ,"alwaysIncludePattern" : false
                         ,"backups" : 10
                         ,"category" : "log4js.file" 
                     }
                 }
             ]
             ,"replaceConsole" : true
        }
    );

    return Log4js;
})();
```

When the times of loop were small, though the memory increased and
never fell down, it worked well. But when the times were set to more
than 10,000,000, it would fail and prompted as followed:

```
...
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525074.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525075.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525076.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525077.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525078.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525079.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525080.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525081.
[2015-12-14 11:23:12.480] [INFO] log4js_main - info message 2525082.

<--- Last few GCs --->

  420299 ms: Scavenge 1399.0 (1457.4) -> 1399.0 (1457.4) MB, 2.3 / 0 ms (+ 0.0 ms in 1 steps since l
ast GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
  421110 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.0 (1457.4) -> 1399.0 (1457.4) MB, 814.3 / 0 ms (+ 15.0 ms in 2 steps si
nce start of marking, biggest step 15.0 ms) [last resort gc].
  421937 ms: Mark-sweep 1399.0 (1457.4) -> 1399.0 (1457.4) MB, 828.6 / 0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000019446CE3AD1 <JS Object>
    1: nextTick [node.js:~491] [pc=0000037DBBD17738] (this=0000012811B14929 <a process with map 0000
02F23C011991>,callback=0000017AB4E49C01 <JS Function afterWrite (SharedFunctionInfo 000002DC70230AF1
)>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 5->1
    3: onwrite(aka onwrite) [_stream_writable.js:~315] [pc=0000037DBB93CC17] (this=0000019446C04189
<undefined>,stream=000000727BB2BEE1 <a WriteStream wit...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

**PS**

As my first question in stackoverflow.com, I want to share things
bothered me a long time. So comes to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

It's necessary to give the logger a chance to do the I/O work by
setImmediate() and use event instead of 'for' to do the loop, or it
will keep the content in the memory and die for out of memory.

**Root Cause**

This is caused by [the event loop mechanisms of nodejs](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod), **bool ev_run (loop, int flags)**, it takes an task
from watchers each time by this order:

```
idle -> I/O -> check
```

The '**for**' and '**process.nextTick()**' are idle watchers, so the
logger doesn't have a chance to do the underlying I/O work. And it
cause the memory running out.

**Solution**

So, we need to give the logger a chance to do the underlying work.

**main.js for log4js**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    const WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME = "work-done";
    const WORK_TIMES = 100 * 1000 * 1000;

    let evem = new (require("events").EventEmitter)();

    // Explicitly listening on the event.
    evem.on(WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME, function(){
        // setImmediate: after I/O operations
        setImmediate(doWork);
    });

    let log4js = require("./log4js-config.js");
    let logger = log4js.getLogger("log4js_main");

    let idx = 0;
    function doWork(){
        idx++;
        if(idx >= WORK_TIMES){
            console.timeEnd(WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME);
            return;
        }
        logger.info(idx);
        setImmediate(function(){
            evem.emit(WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME);
        });
    }

    console.time(WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME);
    doWork();
})();
```

**log4js-config.js (keeps the same)**

**main.js for winston**

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    const WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME = "work-done";
    const WORK_TIMES = 100 * 1000 * 1000;

    let evem = new (require("events").EventEmitter)();
    let logger = require("./winston-config");

    // Explicitly listening on the event.
    evem.on(WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME, function(){
        // setImmediate: after I/O operations
        setImmediate(doWork);
    });

    let idx = 0;
    function doWork(){
        idx++;
        if(idx >= WORK_TIMES){
            console.timeEnd(WORK_TIMES);
            return;
        }
        logger.silly(idx, function(err, level, msg, meta){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            evem.emit(WORK_DONE_EVENT_NAME);
        });
    }

    console.time(WORK_TIMES);
    doWork();
})();
```

**winston-config.js**

```
module.exports = (function(){
    "use strict";
    let Winston = require("winston");
    let WinstonDailyRotateFile = require("winston-daily-rotate-file");
    let transports = [
            new (Winston.transports.Console)({
                "colorize" : true
                ,"timestamp" : true
                ,"showLevel": true
                ,"level" : "silly"
            })
            ,new (Winston.transports.File)({
                "name" : "winston-file"
                ,"filename" : "./logs/winston_size.log"
                ,"maxsize" : 209715200
                , "_maxsize" : "200M = 200 * 1024 * 1024 = 209715200"
                ,"maxFiles" : 1024
                ,"timestamp" : true
                ,"showLevel": true
                ,"level": "silly"
            })
            ,new (WinstonDailyRotateFile)({
              "name" : "winston-daily-file"
              ,"filename" : "./logs/winston_date"
              ,"datePattern" : "-yyyyMMdd.log"
              ,"maxsize" : 209715200
              , "_maxsize" : "200M = 200 * 1024 * 1024 = 209715200"
              ,"maxFiles" : 10
              ,"timestamp" : true
              ,"level": "silly"
            })
        ];
    let logger = new (Winston.Logger)({
        "transports" : transports
    });
    return logger;
})();
```